# Azure webrole act as proxy for third party api

Tags: asp.net, api, azure

I'm currently looking into developing an azure hosted web service to act as a proxy between my mobile app and a third party web service in order to keep my API secret. I haven't a great deal if experience with azure architecture and was wondering if someone might be able to provide some guidance.

Thinking about this problem my first thought would be to host an asp.net web API on azure, send the data from the phone to the azure API acting as a proxy which would receive the web request, then forward the info. With the  API secret to the web service via another httpwebrequest and then returning that response as the original API call response.

Firstly, would this work? And secondly, if I was to have one web role performing this task would it only be able to field one request at a time, having to wait for one request to return from the third party before sending of a request from another phone? This could prove to be a problem if the call to the third party takes a second or so I guess in terms of scalability.

Any other architecture suggestions as to how I can do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know ASP.NET Web API is not yet supported on Azure (YET), Windows Azure only runs .NET 4 runtime, there are ways around this to run MVC 4 on Azure but its not officially supported yet.

You can certainly have a proxy service that intercepts your request and then relays it on, the architecture does sound a little convoluted but you might/must have valid reason for it. I would try an embrace HTTP (REST) for all communication from your clients for maximum interop and also to reduce latency.

Your second question is about scaling out, you should never run one instance of your Web Role as this does not meet the Azure SLA (2 minimum). You should also always strive for asynch programming/design when you are looking to build internet scalable apps. If you build a stateless WCF Service then you can horizontally scale to cater for more traffic. If you have global reach from your consumers you could also use Windows Azure Traffic Manager across geolocated instances of your service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg197529

HTH

Comment: ah thanks for that, hadn't realised it wasn't supported and the link for the traffic is useful for future scalability. I agree that a wcf service would be more suitable for this as its actually supported.
Would the WCF service call the third party API itself or let a worker role do this and return the result back to the webrole which in turn sends it back to the user?

Comment: The WCF Service would be better fitted to run on a WebRole (you get IIS for hosting), you can run it on a WorkerRole but I don't see the point, hosting in IIS on a WebRole is a lot easier. The Service (WCF/ASP.NET Web API) would sits on a Role, accept the public facing from your mobile, call your internal 3rd party API and then send the response back to your consumers.

Answer (score 1):

It will "work" if you mean the proxy setup will function as a normal web service... but I don't think it has much chance of keeping your API secret.  If anyone wants to learn, they will do so easily (all they'd have to do is look at network traffic).

For the second question: there are multiple threads running in IIS/Azure (without having to configure anything).  The latency will slow down your site for obvious reasons (two requests instead of one), and the latency during the proxy request will occupy more worker threads than otherwise; but this shouldn't be a big concern unless you're expecting massive traffic to your site.

Comment: thanks very much for your response. In regards to the second part do you mean worker threads within the web role or separate worker role instances?